# Float округление

Tags: java, android

Нужно в приложении вычеслить разность 2х чисел.2 floata , ответ получаю типо `1.2 -4e`  как  сделать чтоб выводит без этих `-e` .

Answer (score 2):

```
String.format("%.2f", floatValue);
```

Не стесняйтесь пользоваться поиском!

Comment: JVİc Спасибо но этож урезает .И на сколько это правильно ?

Comment: Неужели не предусмотрено в джаве ничего для этого.:

Comment: @elik что значит урезает? `String.format("%.2f", 2.345) == 2,35`